# Update a single column in dataframe based on count of individual segment of my data

Tags: r

1.I want to update a data frame of single column with "misc" where column name not in 
'marketing' | 'OLD_Data' | 'business owner' | 'team communication'| 'sales' | 'YOUTUBE' | 'internal team' |'GAMING' | 'VIDEOS' | 'EDUCATION' |'marketing agency'.
for that below code used:

```
data4$individual_segment<-apply(data4$individual_segment,1,function(x){ if (!data4$individual_segment == 'marketing' | 'OLD_Data' | 'business owner' | 'team communication'
              | 'sales' | 'YOUTUBE' | 'internal team' |'GAMING' | 'VIDEOS' | 'EDUCATION' |'marketing agency')  'misc'})

    data4$segment<-ifelse(data4$individual_segment=='marketing' | 'OLD_Data' | 'business owner' | 'team communication'
| 'sales' | 'YOUTUBE' | 'internal team' |'GAMING' | 'VIDEOS' | 'EDUCATION' |'marketing agency',1,0)
```

2.also i want to update based on count based :
table(data4$individual_segment) gives me the below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ybfO.png)

so if freq<=9 then every row in data4$individual_segment has to replace with "misc"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

pattern <- 'marketing|OLD_Data|business owner|team communication|sales|YOUTUBE|internal team|GAMING|VIDEOS|EDUCATION|marketing agency'

data4 %>% 
  group_by(individual_segment) %>% 
  mutate(count=n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(segment=ifelse(str_detect(individual_segment, pattern) | count<=9, 
                        'misc', individual_segment))
```

Alternatively, if you're not looking for strings contained in `individual_segment` but exact matches, you can do the following:

```
misc.vect <- c('marketing', 'OLD_Data', 'business owner', 'team communication', 
               'sales', 'YOUTUBE', 'internal team', 'GAMING', 'VIDEOS', 
               'EDUCATION', 'marketing agency')

data4 %>% 
  group_by(individual_segment) %>% 
  mutate(count=n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(segment=ifelse(individual_segment %in% misc.vect | count<=9, 
                        'misc', individual_segment))
```

Comment: sorry buddy...Vari1 and Freq are getting only i run data.frame(table(data4$individual_segment)) ...so please dont mind for not mentioning it. instead of Var1 what can i use in the above code?

Comment: Sorry - I wrote the code without testing it (is is usually useful if you include the data by `dput`'ing it in the question). I just replaced `Var1` with `individual_segment`. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dplyr. You just need the `%in%` operator.

If you need frequency > 9 then:

```
names.rle = rle(sort(data$individual_segment)) # list of names and their frequences
names.frequent = names.rle$val[names.rle$freq > 9]  # vector of frequent names
data$individual_segment[!(data$individual_segment %in% names.frequent)] = "misc"
```

If you need specific list of names then

```
names.frequent = c("marketing", "OLD_Data", "business_owner") # specify all of them
data$individual_segment[!(data$individual_segment %in% names.frequent)] = "misc"
```

Comment: names.rle = rle(sort(data4$individual_segment)) # list of names and their frequences
Error in rle(sort(data4$individual_segment)) : 
  'x' must be a vector of an atomic type  : getting error like this

Comment: I see you mentioned 'you don't need `dplyr`'. Many things that are done in `dplyr` can be done using base R. However, the code would be less readable and the development process generally not as smooth.

Comment: @ssds Check at what part of the code the error is.  Do you have data4$individual_segment?  Is it a vector of strings?

Comment: data4$individual_segment[!(data4$individual_segment %in% names.frequent)] = "misc"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, !(data4$individual_segment %in% names.frequent),  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @user31264 yes ..data4$individual_segment is of factor type of data...can i change to char type?

Comment: @user31264 thanks buddy...code is worked when i changed the factor to char and executed the second part code. it worked ,superb and thanks for the quick response. Vlad C. thank u buddy for help and fast response